# Calculation of the Covariance of Gaussian Mixtures

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a Gaussian mixture model, given by:
$$
X \sim \sum_{i = 1}^M \alpha_i N_p(\mu_i, C_i)
$$
such that $\sum_{i=1}^M\alpha_i =1 $.
Is there a way I can compute the overall covariance matrix if $x$? I would like to say "$X$ has a covariance matrix given by $C$".

Comment: Is $x$ a vector, or a scalar random variable?

Comment: Please avoid using acronyms. Using expanded names allows for ease of searching, and invites those uninitiated to look the term up and learn about it.

Comment: Removed the tag [tag:gauss-sum] as that refers to a [different concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum).

Comment: My answer is at least simpler than the others.  But also, I think it's the more-or-less natural way to do it and uses a technique that ought to become habitual for anyone who works with expectations and variances.

Comment: @shasha : vectors.. sorry about that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
You can write $x = y + \text{error}$, where $y = \mu_i$ with probability $\alpha_i$, for $i=1,\ldots,M$, and the *conditional* probability distribution of the "error" *given* $y$ is $N(0,C_i)$.  Then we have
$$
E(x) = E(E(x\mid y)) = E\left.\begin{cases} \vdots \\  \mu_i & \text{with probability }\alpha_i \\  \vdots \end{cases}\right\} = \sum_{i=1}^M\alpha_i\mu_i,
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\var(x) = {} & E(\var(x\mid y)) + \var(E(x \mid y)) \\[12pt]
= {} & E\left.\begin{cases} \vdots \\  C_i & \text{with probability }\alpha_i \\  \vdots \end{cases}\right\} \\
& {} + \var\left.\begin{cases} \vdots \\ \mu_i & \text{with probability }\alpha_i \\   \vdots \end{cases} \right\} \\[12pt]
= {} & \sum_{i=1}^M \alpha_i C_i + \sum_{i=1}^M \alpha_i(\mu_i-\bar\mu)(\mu_i-\bar\mu)^T,
\end{align}
$$
where $\bar\mu=\sum_{i=1}^M \alpha_i\mu_i$.

Comment: Aren't you missing probabilities $\alpha_i$ in the last two summations in your answer? You seem to be using $\alpha_i = M^{-1}$ for all $i$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate : Fixed.  Yes, it's weighted average with generally unequal weights.

Comment: @MichaelHardy So, here $var(x)$ is the covariance matrix user is looking at, am I right?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you may clear [one more doubt of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284464/covariance-from-gaussian-mixture-model-versus-direct-calculation) regarding covariance matrices, that would be great. Thanks for replying promptly yesterday.

Answer (score 18):

A mixture model commonly refers to a weighted sum of densities, not a weighted sum of random variables as in Sasha's answer As a simplest example, a (scalar)
random variable $Z$ is said to have a mixture Gaussian density if its 
probability density function is
$$f_Z(z)=\alpha f_X(z)+(1−\alpha)f_Y(z), ~0<\alpha<1$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables with different densities, 
that is, $(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)\neq(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$.  It follows straightforwardly
that
$$\begin{aligned}
E[Z]&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty zf_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz&
&= \alpha\mu_X + (1-\alpha)\mu_Y\\
E[Z^2]&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2f_Z(z)\,\mathrm dz&
&= \alpha(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2) + (1-\alpha)(\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2)\\
\text{var}(Z) &= E[Z^2] - (E[Z])^2&
&= \alpha(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2) + (1-\alpha)(\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2) - [\alpha\mu_X + (1-\alpha)\mu_Y]^2
\end{aligned}$$
which unfortunately does not simplify to a pretty formula.

More generally, a mixture density would have $n, n > 1,$ terms
with positive weights $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n$ summing to $1$.
It is simplest to think of a partition of the sample space into
events $A_k, 1 \leq k \leq n$, with $P(A_k) = \alpha_k$.
Then, $Z$ is a random variable whose
*conditional distribution* given $A_k$ is a Gaussian distribution
$f_k(z) \sim N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$, and thus the *unconditional* distribution is, via the
law of total probability,
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k f_k(z).$$
The ungainly expression $\alpha(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2) + (1-\alpha)(\sigma_Y^2 + \mu_Y^2) - [\alpha\mu_X + (1-\alpha)\mu_Y]^2$ derived earlier
for the variance of
$Z$ can thus be manipulated into
$$\bigr[\alpha\sigma_X^2 + (1-\alpha)\sigma_Y^2\bigr] 
+ \biggr(\bigr[\alpha\mu_X^2 + (1-\alpha)\mu_Y^2\bigr] 
- \bigr[\alpha\mu_X + (1-\alpha)\mu_Y\bigr]^2\biggr)$$
which, while still not pretty, can be identified 
as an illustration of the conditional variance formula:

> The variance of $Z$ is the mean of the conditional variance plus the
>   variance of the conditional mean.

When $Z$ is a vector random variable whose conditional distributions
are jointly Gaussian with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $C_i$,
similar calculations can be done, and the unconditional covariance
matrix computed. Suppose that the conditional density of $Z$ given $A_k$
is
a jointly Gaussian density with mean vector $\mu^{(k)}$ and
covariance matrix $C^{(k)}$.  Then,
$$E[Z_i] = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_i^{(k)} ~\text{and}~
E[Z_iZ_j] = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \bigr(C_{i,j}^{(k)} + \mu_i^{(k)}\mu_j^{(k)}\bigr)$$
giving
$$\begin{align}C_{i,j} = \text{cov}(Z_i,Z_j)
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \bigr(C_{i,j}^{(k)} + \mu_i^{(k)}\mu_j^{(k)}\bigr)
- \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_i^{(k)}\right)
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_j^{(k)}\right)\\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k C_{i,j}^{(k)}\right)
 + \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_i^{(k)}\mu_j^{(k)}
- \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_i^{(k)}\right)
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \mu_j^{(k)}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$
which is an illustration of the conditional covariance formula:

> The covariance of two random variables is the mean of
>   the conditional covariances plus the covariance of the
>   conditional means.

Comment: Could you explain how you get $E[Z_iZ_j] = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \bigr(C_{i,j}^{(k)} + \mu_i^{(k)}\mu_j^{(k)}\bigr)$ ? Thank you

Comment: @Pop $E[Z_i Z_j] = E_A[ E[ Z_i Z_j | A ] ] = E_A[ Cov[Z_i|A, Z_j|A] + E[Z_i|A] E[Z_j|A] ]$

Answer (score 6):

Motivated by the answer provided by Michael Hardy, a formal solution to such question might be formulated as follows:

By introducing a new hidden variable $I$ to represent the identity of the local model, the probability of the Gaussian mixtures can be decomposed as:
$$p(x|I=i)=\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,C_i)$$
$$p(I=i)=\alpha_i$$
Therefore,
$$E(x)=E[E(x|I=i)]=\sum_{i=1}^{M} \alpha_i \mu_i$$
\begin{align}
Var(x)&=E[Var(x|I=i)]+Var[E(x|I=i)] \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^{M} \alpha_i C_i + \sum_{i=1}^{M} \alpha_i (\mu_i-\bar{\mu})(\mu_i-\bar{\mu})^T
\end{align}
where $\bar{\mu}=E(x)$. Moreover, the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and [Law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) have been used in above two equations.